# Connecting to a MySQL Server over WAN

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, tcp

I have setup a MySQL 5.6 Server on an Ubuntu 14.04 Server distribution on Virtualbox, and am trying to connect to it via TCP/IP from the host Linux Mint 17 Desktop OS over the WAN.

Connection through the MySQL client on the VM works fine, but whenever a connection is attempted from the host machine (via mysql-client-5.6 package) an error comes back with one of 2 errors:

```
INPUT: $ mysql -u client -p
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

or

```
INPUT:  $ mysql -u client -p protocol=tcp -h 127.0.0.1
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Server Setup:

- Fresh Ubuntu 14.04 Server installation with only mysql-server-5.6 and openssl packages installed from Ubuntu APT repository.
- Users created are 'root'@'%' and 'client'@'%', both with full privileges given to them.
- Iptables was modified to try and fix the issue (it came completely stripped)  and shows: accept tcp connection from mysql and shows:
  target: ACCEPT  prot: tcp  opt: --  source: anywhere  destination: anywhere  tcp dpt:mysql .
- Configuration file "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" was hardly touched, only tried to change bind-address to values 127.0.0.1 , 0.0.0.0 , commented : all unsuccessful. Server and Client socket is set to 3306.
- "service mysql status" returns output: "mysql start/running, process 10650"
- Checked that tcp port 3306 is being listened to through "netstat -tulpn" command. returns output: PID=tcp6   Local Address=:::3306   Foreign Address=:::*   State=LISTEN .

Client Setup:

- Installed package mysql-client-5.6 from Ubuntu APT repository
- All configurations are preset and untouched.

Would like an affirmation on the following: Was getting the idea that connecting through Unix socket is only possible through the OS hosting the server (internally), while any external OS has to use TCP/IP and so I tried the "protocol=tcp" bit in my 2nd input.

Was searching for a solution for over 2 days now, starting to feel really frustrated. Any useful help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Was getting the idea that connecting through Unix socket is only possible through the OS hosting the server (internally),"  Correct.

Comment: What are you trying to do: Connect from host A to host B?

Comment: Check your firewall and database grants

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen: Trying to use MySQL Client/Server architecture, Server on VM, Client on Desktop. user2182349: Firewall has not been touched on both systems (no rules) as I mentioned, about second suggestion I'm not trying to connect to a single database, but to the mysql client console itself. Both users have the full user privileges with option grants.

Comment: And you are using this command on your client: **mysql -u client -p protocol=tcp -h 127.0.0.1** ? (Just trying to get the question 100% understood)

Comment: Yes on the Desktop client (not Server machine), among other variations: **mysql -u client -p protocol=tcp -h 10.0.2.15**          <== eth0 inet address on server , without a bind-address set in configuration. getting: 'ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.2.15' (110)'